# Silverlight/Wpf scale control

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I have one silverlight control and i want to add it scale property. 
I will try to describe what i want.
Imagine you have a table that looks great on 1600x1200 resolution, but on 800x600 it sucks because all rows and columns become 2 times smaller but font stays original size. 
So i want to know if there is some technique allows me to tell control to reneder like 1600x1200 and then say scale 0.5.

I am looking for this solution because we already have great program with nice design, but it looks ugly on notebook screen and i want to fix that as easy as possible.

Also i am using telerik, but their fluid control is not what i want.

Comment: You mean like the [`ScaleTransform` Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.scaletransform(v=vs.95).aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at the [`ScaleTransform` Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.scaletransform(v=vs.95).aspx) page on MSDN. Here's a short example of how you could use it:

```
<YourPrefix:YourUserControl ... >
    <YourPrefix:YourUserControl.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5" />
    </YourPrefix:YourUserControl.RenderTransform>
</YourPrefix:YourUserControl>
```

This would scale your control by a factor of 0.5, but these scale factors can also be data bound.